# How do I use a prefix route to check all connections on that route for a certain value, and return a simply plain text on failure?

Tags: cakephp, url-routing, cakephp-2.1

I have an unusual situation in which I need to have a special route prefix that handles authentication very differently from normal.  Basically, any requests on this route prefix are given rights in "isAuthorized" (on the app controller), and the layout is set to a special layout for this connection.  So far the following works just fine:

```
if(isset($this->params['special']) && $this->params['special'])
{
    $this->layout = 'special';
    return true;        
}
```

What needs to happen in addition to this is that every time a request is made, a key/token combo will be checked against the database for a valid entry.  If the entry is not valid, I need to use the special layout to output only "Invalid key/token combo".  If the entry is valid, it will proceed as normal.

Where would be the appropriate place to put this check so that all connections on that route prefix are checked, and how do I go about sending only that text on a failure?  Is there a way to change the route so that a different controller and view is used if the authentication fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh now I think I understand.

You want to run a check before every action, to see if the parameter passed token/key is valid.

This would be done within your controller in the beforefilter function.

```
public function beforeFilter()
{
    if(!isset($this->params['special']))
    {
        $this->render('fail_view');
        exit;
    }    
}
```

Here you could run your check on the parameters being passed, if they fail validation then you can render a custom view with whatever text you want and then exit the rest of the script.

Comment: Well, I can do the logical aspects of checking the key/token.  The main issue I'm having is how to return the invalid token message without ANY other text.  I've got a layout that doesn't include anything other than the content, but how do I submit just that line to it, and then stop, so that it doesn't try to process the rest of the route?

Comment: @xtraorange I think I know what you want know, please check my edited answer.

Comment: For some reason, that's rendering a blank page.  I never would have thought this would be so difficult.  I know it's bad practice, but I'm thinking perhaps I should just echo a response and exit?

Comment: @xtraorange you need to create the view fail_view.ctp and put it in the folder with the rest of that controllers views.